# What are the most accurate Chinese to English translation APIs?

Tags: translation, meaning

I want to convert Chinese sentences into English using a web API or open source web project. I want to automate this process so I think the best way is a web API. Most of the translators do not give accurate results. Can you please tell me what is the best web API or web project to do this translation?

Comment: I don't think, to this day, there is any completely satisfying implementation of translation from any language to any other language. To be sure, translation between languages from dissimilar families would be much harder, than between similar ones. The former is the case of Chinese-to-English translation. I guess what makes it so hard is the lack of declension in Chinese, but such information must be supplemented in English and can only be referred from context.

Answer (score 3):

As a native speaker and a programmer myself, I have not found any good translation engine that does a good job in English/Chinese translation. It sucks because most of the engines are more or less doing literal translation, while for Chinese, understanding the context is the important part of how to translate a sentence. Something needs AI to achieve that.